# Running audio thread prevents touchscreen input until it has finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have a written a program for ipad that processes a midi file into an array and I then use the array to play the piece using a loop.

```
for (int j=pieceposition;j<100;j++){ 
        xxx=midiplay[50][pieceposition]; 
       int  i=0; 
        while(midiplay[i][pieceposition]){ 
            noteNum=midiplay[i][pieceposition];i++; 
            onVelocity=midiplay[i][pieceposition];i++; 
            MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnit, noteOnCommand, noteNum,onVelocity, 0); 
            i++;} 
        pieceposition++; 
        usleep(xxx);
if(ENDLOOP){break;} 
    }
```

My question is how can I use input from the touchscreen to stop this loop part way through- to change ENDLOOP from 0 to 1? 
The thread running the audio loop seems to prevent any touchscreen input until the loop has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that you are trying to do your playback on the main thread, and during the playback, you are making the main thread sleep. The main thread is in charge of the UI and all interactions between the touchscreen and the device are processed through the main thread. Hence, if the main thread is being used (or being made to sleep) by any process, the UI will become unresponsive.

In my opinion, you could use the Grand Central Dispatch (gcd) to send your playback code to a background thread. This ensures that the main thread is free to respond to any touch events. You could achieve that by using the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (int j=pieceposition;j<100;j++){
        xxx=midiplay[50][pieceposition];
        int  i=0;
        while(midiplay[i][pieceposition]){
            noteNum=midiplay[i][pieceposition];i++;
            onVelocity=midiplay[i][pieceposition];i++;
            MusicDeviceMIDIEvent(self.samplerUnit, noteOnCommand, noteNum,onVelocity, 0);
            i++;}
        pieceposition++;
        usleep(xxx);
        if(ENDLOOP){break;} 
    }
});
```

I am using your code exactly, except putting it within a dispatch statement, so that it will be executed by a background thread.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the answer helps you, as I think it should, please help by up-voting/accepting it. Let me know if you have specific questions about the answer.